# Correct spelling of 'timestamp': one or two words?

Tags: orthography

Something I'm wondering about is the correct usage of the word(s) 'timestamp'. I don't know whether it's one (timestamp) or two (time stamp) words, and googling for the answer doesn't help me in finding an answer.

Consulting two sources which I believe to be reliable ones:

[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/timestamp) (which looks like it's affiliated with the actual university) says it's 'timestamp';

whereas [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/time%20stamp) says it's 'time stamp'.

Oxford Dictionaries is British and Merriam-Webster is American, and I'm assuming these sites reflect their respective spelling rules. Which may explain the difference here. However, if I'm not mistaken, with words like these it's normally the other way around; i.e. the American spelling using it as one concatenated word, and the British spelling as two separate words.

Is my assumption about the American vs. Brisish spelling correct? Which, if any, of the two forms is correct?

Comment: @Lawrence Oops, typo! :p Someone already fixed it :)

Comment: If you have a style guide that says to use a particular dictionary, use that. Otherwise, it's subjective. Just be prepared to defend whatever spelling you use. And to then use it consistently.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to what  [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=timestamp%3Aeng_us_2012%2Ctime%20stamp%3Aeng_us_2012%2Ctimestamp%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Ctime%20stamp%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctimestamp%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctime%20stamp%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctimestamp%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctime%20stamp%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0) shows  it appears that the one word  version “*timestamp*” is the more commonly used both in AmE and BrE.

Comment: Interesting to know, but honestly I don't find this a reliable source of what is the right usage, especially when it comes to data based off Google searches. Nearly everyone says 'less people' but the correct usage is nevertheless 'fewer people'.

Comment: @poepje - not sure what you mean. Both version timestamp and time stamp and possibly time-stamp are used.  It is a question of which is the more commonly used, not which is the "correct" one.

Comment: Of course it is. There are set rules for spelling in each language, you can't just ignore them because many people make the same mistake.

Comment: @poepje - you found yourself two reliable dictionaries which give both versions...what makes you think that one is more correct than the other?

Comment: @poepje - also form Cambridge Dictionary: ***timestamp***
noun [ C ] ***also time stamp***. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/timestamp

Comment: no, sorry, what I meant was that because one is more commonly used, it's not that one form that is correct, as I understood from you answer that is what you implied. That said, the fact that the Cambridge page mentions both is a good mention to show that both are indeed correct (though I wonder why the other two sites don't mention that).

Comment: I do still wonder if this is Am. vs Br. spelling though.